# Select segun parametros

Tags: php, html, select

Buenas colegas tengo la siguiente duda con un select...

Tengo el **select** que muestro a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que me gustaría hacer en esto seria que no me muestre las demás opciones solo la primera que seria la primera hora ("6:40 - 7:00"), quiero que vaya en orden, necesito que solo me muestre la primera opción, y cuando ya haya usado la primera opción en algún registro como lo estoy usando, solo me muestre la segunda opción y la primera ya no salga y así consecutivamente.

Este es mi código, realmente simple.

```
<select name="psb_hr" id="psb_hr" class="form-control" onchange='cambioOpciones();' required/>
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
                    <option value="04">06:40 - 07:00</option>
                    <option value="05">07:00 - 08:00</option>
                    <option value="06">08:00 - 09:00</option>
                    <option value="07">09:00 - 10:00</option>
                    <option value="08">10:00 - 11:00</option>
                    <option value="09">11:00 - 12:00</option>
                    <option value="10">12:00 - 13:00</option>
                    <option value="11">13:00 - 14:00</option>
                    <option value="12">14:00 - 15:00</option>
                    <option value="13">15:00 - 16:10</option>
                    <option value="14">16:10 - 17:00</option>
                    <option value="15">17:00 - 18:00</option>
                    <option value="16">18:00 - 19:00</option>
                    <option value="17">19:00 - 20:00</option>
                    <option value="18">20:00 - 21:00</option>
                    <option value="19">21:00 - 22:16</option>
                    <option value="20">22:16 - 23:00</option>
                    <option value="21">23:00 - 00:00</option>
                    <option value="22">00:00 - 01:00</option>
                    <option value="23">01:00 - 02:00</option>
                    <option value="24">02:00 - 03:00</option>
                    <option value="25">03:00 - 04:00</option>
                    <option value="26">04:00 - 05:00</option>
                    <option value="27">05:00 - 06:00</option>
                    <option value="28">06:00 - 06:40</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Deberías almacenar esos datos en una tabla con una `PK`.

Comment: Opino lo mismo que @Bicho. Antes que nada debes almacenar las opciones en una tabla de tu base de datos para a la hora de generar el select antes consultar por las opciones que ya estan utilizadas para no mostrarlas.

Comment: Una vez creada la tabla, cual seria la manera?

Comment: Consultas el último elemento guardado y solo muestras el siguiente.